# Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Prove $\lambda = 2$ or $3$ or $4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T\in(V)$ and $(T-2I)(T-3I)(T-4I) = 0$. Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Prove $\lambda = 2$ or $\lambda = 3$ or $\lambda = 4$

What properties of polynomials will prove this?

Comment: Does $T\in(V)$ mean $T$ is an endomorphism of $V$?

Comment: Start with the definition of eigenvalue.

Comment: this follow from the definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows immediately from the property that the eigenvalues of an operator $T$ are the roots of its minimal polynomial.

The hypothesis means that $T$ satisfies the polynomial $(X-2)(X-3)(X-4)$, so the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides $p(X):=(X-2)(X-3)(X-4)$. The eigenvalues of $T$ are precisely the roots of the minimal polynomial (not counting algebraic multiplicity, I suppose), so since any root of the minimal polynomial is a root of $p(X)$, this root can only be $2$, $3$, or $4$.

Answer (score 1):

If $3$ and $4$ are not eigenvalues of $T$, then $T-3I$ and $T-4I$ are invertible. What then does that say about $T-2I$ (based on your equation above)? (Repeat this logic for the other two cases.)

As Bungo notes below, this only shows one of $2,3,4$ are eigenvalues (which I somehow assumed was what was meant). For completeness since the answer was already accepted, I will restate the remainder of the proof. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $x$ its corresponding eigenvector, then

$$0 = (T-2I)(T-3I)(T-4I)x = (T-2I)(T-3I)(\lambda-4)x = \cdots = (\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)(\lambda-4)x$$

which is zero if and only if $\lambda$ is one of $2,3,4$.

Comment: This shows that at least one of $2$, $3$, or $4$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. But does it show that these are the only possible eigenvalues?

Comment: Hmm. Good point. I misinterpreted the post a little bit. I guess to show that these are the only ones, the way to do it is via dimension counting.

Comment: One might reason as follows. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $x$ is a corresponding eigenvector, then $$(T-2I)(T-3I)(T - 4I)x = (T-2I)(T-3I)(\lambda - 4)x  = (T-2I)(\lambda-3)(\lambda-4)x = (\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)(\lambda-4)x$$ Since $x$ is nonzero and $(T-2I)(T-3I)(T-4I) = 0$, this forces $\lambda = 2$ or $3$ or $4$.